# Thread Logic in Methods

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance, jakarta-ee

I need to understand how threads run inside methods, for example if i do this

The thread execute and everything its ok

```
private void someMethod()
{
    myThread obj = new myThread();
    obj.start();
}

private class myThread extends Thread {
     @Overrride
     public void run() { 
         // Actions 
     };
}
```

But if i do this the thread got triggered at last (after callAnotherMethod and that random variable declaration) even if i put the thread calling first

```
private void someMethod()
{
    myThread obj = new myThread();
    obj.start();

    callAnotherMethod();
    String someVariable = "";
}

private class myThread extends Thread {
     @Overrride
     public void run() { 
         // Actions 
     };
}
```

My problem its i need to make somethings in the thread to use after in my methods but if i write code this way, my thread got triggered at last. How can i use my thread first and then use another methods ?

Sorry about my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Callable and Future classes. Callable is a thread which returns a Future object once its job is done. You can wait for the Future to become available.
See the example from JavaDoc - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

Answer (score 0):

if you need to execute in sequence... what´s the point on using another thread??

But if you´re running two heavyload operations, one in a background thread and one in current thread, you can call `.join()` and then continue...

Comment: join sounds like a bad idea

Comment: i need to use a thread cause im working in android and server methods only run inside threads

Comment: Blackbelt, I know. Just solving with the supposed tools... ;)

Comment: @eduyayo im gonna try with the async task, i have a huge thread with operations so port to async task gonna take time, but if can solve my issue...

Comment: @eduyayo async task have the same issue